# Format of titles in a dissertation (chapter, section, . . .)

Tags: titles

Where can I find some tutorials for page geometry and margins or formatting of chapters, sections, titles, . . . ?

Thank you,

Comment: The `titlesec` package can do that, unless there are incompatibilities with the class you use.

Comment: In its current form, the question is to broad and unclear to answer. Noone (technically) needs to have a file `format.tex` but everyone is free to have one.

Comment: @Johannes_B I meant the part determining the format of the page, size of titles, . . . that is, the format of the document. I know it is not necessary to have a format.tex file, it was a way to explain it.

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are different packages for page geometry and margins or formatting of chapter and section titles, ...

Comment: Ok, I have simplified the question. It is also general but may be more understandable.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner

Answer (score 0):

For page geometry *A Few Notes on Book Design* (`> texdoc memdesign`) discusses this in general terms. For chapters, sections, etc., then the manual for the `memoir` class (`> texdoc memoir`) chapter *Document divisions* has many examples of different styles and the code to produce them.